# Unable to install printer driver for Canon Pixma mg4250

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, canon

I cannot get my canon pixma mg4250 printer to print on Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried the following:
I downloaded the canon driver file from the UK website (I am in the UK). This provided a zip file into my download folder. I extracted this and now have two entities in my downloads folder, a folder and a file, named respectively:

1. cnijfilter-mg4200series-3.80-1-rpm
2. cnijfilter-mg4200series-3.80-1-rpm.tar.gz

I then tried installing the driver in the terminal by inputting the following:

```
$ `sudo apt install cnijfilter-mg4200series-3.80-1-rpm.tar.gz`
```

This returned the error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package cnijfilter-mg4200series-3.80-1-rpm.tar.gz
```

I clearly don't really understand what I'm doing and would appreciate a clear explanation of how to install the driver in simple english. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For Canon Pixma MG4250 and other "old" Canon printers, the package `cups-backend-bjnp` is needed. First install it:

```
sudo apt install cups-backend-bjnp
```

Then your printer will be avaliable in Ubuntu's list of printers.
And you may change the color model to KCMY.

Comment: Printer now working. Many thanks, user1083006, you've saved me hours (possibly days) of frustration. I've actually no idea what I've installed and why it worked but this will be my next project - learning about linux is a steep learning curve for me.