# Older Canon MP600 printer on 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I've had a Canon MP600 printer/scanner running for years on windows and it still works so I'm hoping to continue to use it on linux.  Currently the scanner works but I cannot print.  I've tried the troubleshooting tool (it did not have a recommendation) and also tried:

```
$sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-MP600series
```

output:

```
E:  Unable to locate package cnijfilter-MP600series
```

After trying that, I searched "cnijfilter" and based on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240015/unable-to-install-printer-driver-for-canon-pixma-mg4250) I tried:

```
$sudo apt install cups-backend-bjnp
```

and the printer does not yet work

Any suggestions?

Comment: Divide your problem into "print" and "scan". They're treated separately. For "print", add your printer via CUPS at `http://localhost:631`. For "scan", you probably have be in the same group as the scanner's `/dev/` file.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  The scanner already works so I am covered there.  Your printer solution works, I followed the http://localhost:631 and entered the printer information and now I can print.